# problem dual booting windows 7 with debian

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

I install windows and resize its partition. I then try to install debian in the remaining space. As it's installing the base system, it consistently gives me the following error message: "No Installable kernel was found in the defined APT source". This has never happened when I just use the entire disk.

I tried ignoring the message and continuing. When it finally started grub 1.99 (this was debian testing), it gave me a prompt asking me to enter a command instead of the normal "select the operating system" screen. I messed around and got another message which said something along the lines of "no kernel is installed."

Why is this happening? What difference does it make that I'm now trying to install onto a smaller partition?

The same thing happens with debian stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I used this single usb to boot different versions of linux in the past and some of the previous configuration files may have screwed something up. After I deleted everything from the usb and made it bootable again, everything worked just fine.

Comment: so it's better to use one but fast flash ..for single install